# Manipulating pretrained layers of convnet in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, caffe

I am learning convolutional networks in Tensorflow. I wonder if there is any tutorials of using TF to investigate a pre-trained convnet model, like these excellent tutorials for Caffe: [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb) and [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb). I mean, how to access middle layers, get its learned parameters and blobs, to customize input shape to accept arbitrary image size or batch size, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite the same thing, but there's a codelab here that shows you how to remove the top layer of a pretrained network and train up a new one on your own data:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0
It might give you some ideas on how to approach this in TensorFlow.

Comment: This is handy and useful. Thanks!